# How would I make my class print out any present children?

Tags: python

So I'm fairly new to python and I'm just creating Linked Lists to get a feel for the language. How would I make a parent LL print out any children links? I'm stuck at this current implementation.

```
class LinkedList:
    def __init__(self, value):
        self.value = value
        self.next = None

    def getNext(self):      #faulty method
        currentNode = self
        if self.next is not None:
            currentNode = next
            return next.value
        

    def __repr__(self):
        return "Current value is: {}. Here are the children links: ".format(self.value)

        ## How would I print out each child link?

one = LinkedList(10)
one.next = LinkedList(3)
one.next.next = LinkedList(4)
one.next.next.next = LinkedList(5)
```

**Edit added the code for adding multiple children to a LL, hoping to be able to print out all children links from the parent class

```
print(one)
```

In this case I'm hoping to read:

`"Current value is: 10. Here are the children links: 3 -> 4 -> 5"`

Comment: What is your desired output?

Comment: return `f"Current value is: {self.value}. Here are the children links: {self.next.value}"`

Comment: Desired output for the above would be: 
"Current value is {}. Here are the children links: 3"

Comment: @leaf_yakitori that returns the next value, yes, but in the case I have multiple children.. is there a way

Comment: So you only want to print the next value? Or would it print more values if the list were longer?

Comment: @Sergio Bost please provide a desired output for multiple children.

Comment: Sorry for the ambiguity, I just updated with desired output

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- you can do it with a simple `while` loop

#### code:

```
class LinkedList:
    def __init__(self, value):
        self.value = value
        self.next = None
        
    def __repr__(self):
        result = f"Current value is: {self.value}. Here are the children links:"
        idx = 0
        while self.next != None:
            result = f"{result} {self.next.value}" if idx == 0 else f"{result} -> {self.next.value}"
            idx += 1
            self = self.next
        return result

one = LinkedList(10)
one.next = LinkedList(3)
one.next.next = LinkedList(4)
one.next.next.next = LinkedList(5)
print(one)
```

#### result:

```
Current value is: 10. Here are the children links: 3 -> 4 -> 5
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do the `__repr__` recursively:

```
    def __repr__(self):
        return "Current value is: {}. Here are the children links:\n{}".format(self.value, self.next)
```

```
Current value is: 10. Here are the children links:
Current value is: 3. Here are the children links:
None
```

For multiple links:

```
lls = [
    LinkedList(10),
    LinkedList(3),
    LinkedList(78),
    LinkedList(-56),
    LinkedList(5),
]

lls[0].next = lls[1]
lls[1].next = lls[2]
lls[2].next = lls[3]
lls[3].next = lls[4]

print(lls[0])
```

```
Current value is: 10. Here are the children links:
Current value is: 3. Here are the children links:
Current value is: 78. Here are the children links:
Current value is: -56. Here are the children links:
Current value is: 5. Here are the children links:
None
```

Comment: Nice thanks, would it be trivial to make a one liner?

Answer (score 1):

Here are a couple more alternatives for your `__repr__` method.

Build the list of children then convert to a string using `str.join`:

```
    def __repr__(self):
        children = []
        node = self.next
        while node is not None:
            children.append(str(node.value))
            node = node.next

        children_str = " -> ".join(children)
        return f"Current value is: {self.value}. Here are the children links: {children_str}"
```

Or you could use recursion:

```
    def __repr__(self):
        def children(node):
            if node.next is None:Nne
                return str(node.value)
            else:
                return f"{node.value} -> {children(node.next)}"

        return f"Current value is: {self.value}. Here are the children links: {children(self.next)}"
```